# AVCaptureDeviceFormat x Battery Life

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, batterylevel

Will running an `AVCaptureDevice` at a 1920x1080 `AVCaptureDeviceFormat` consume more battery than a format at say 640x480?

If on say an iPhone Plus, where there exists a resolution exactly equal to the screen resolution, you're at least saving a resizing operation on the GPU (I'm using Metal).

Is upsizing from 640x480 to 1920x1080 a more expensive operation than say, downsizing from 3840x2160 to 1920x1080?

Running an app with a camera background, that also uses the camera to capture media... so trying to make some intelligent battery life decisions on choose formats.

Comment: While I think you have good intentions here. This might be a case of premature optimization. I don't think there will be a noticeable difference unless a user spend their entire battery life on the app.

Comment: @gadu in my messenger, i'm encode media at the target user's resolution. So there are cases of like iPhone 7 -> iPhone X where I would need to use a 3840x2160 resolution format, and then size down to approx 2400x1300. So I'm debating always running the camera at those super high resolutions (vs much lower native device res)... to avoid the momentary stutter in the feed when swapping formats. (Since it's a camera background... you'd always see that transition). Wondering at what cost tho..